# Exibir valores numéricos sem notação científica em select do Oracle

Tags: oracle

Tenho que fazer vários selects no Oracle utilizando o SQLPLUS exibindo várias informações para serem guardadas em arquivo texto. Algumas tabelas possuem campos numéricos do tipo NUMBER(19). Alguns desses campos possuem valores que são muito altos de forma que Oracle  os exiba em notação científica como 8.0E+13. Eu sei que se eu utilizar um to_char(campo, '999999999999999') eu consigo formatar o campo, mas eu não quero fazer isso, pois são muitas tabelas e campos. Existe alguma forma de eu formatar a saída para que todos os campos numéricos sejam exibidos sem notação científica? Segue um código de exemplo.

```
    create table teste_numerico(
      numero number(19)
    );

    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003147);                      
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003153);                       
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003163);                     
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003170);                       
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003176);                       
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003181);                       
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003188);                       
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003194);                       
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003199);                       
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003206);                       
    insert into teste_numerico values (80000000003212);
```

Select sem formatação:

```
    select *
      from teste_numerico;
```

Resultado:

```
        NUMERO
    ----------
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 
       8.0E+13 

     11 linhas selecionadas
```

Select com formatação:

```
    select to_char(numero, '999999999999999')
      from teste_numerico;
```

Resultado:

```
    TO_CHAR(NUMERO,'999999999999999')
    ---------------------------------
      80000000003147                  
      80000000003153                  
      80000000003163                  
      80000000003170                  
      80000000003176                  
      80000000003181                  
      80000000003188                  
      80000000003194                  
      80000000003199                  
      80000000003206                  
      80000000003212                  

     11 linhas selecionadas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser utilizado o ***numformat***

```
set numformat 99999999999
select *
       from teste_numerico;
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado.